# PHPMailer fail smtp connexion after X emails sent

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I use PHPMailer with my own server, in my IP adress, and after couple hundred of emails successfully sent, no more sending...

PHPMailer said fail SMTP connexion.
Here is the lines I use:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host      = 'my IP';
$mail->Username  = 'mail@my domain';
$mail->Password  = 'my password';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port       = 25;
$mail->From       = 'my mail';
$mail->FromName   = 'my name';

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject    = 'sujet';
$mail->addAddress('an email');
$mail->Body    = 'some html';
$mail->AltBody = 'some txt';
$mail->send()
$mail->clearAddresses(); // I use a boucle
```

So why PHPMailer no longer succeed to keep the smtp connexion after some sending ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you sure the coding is causing the error? Because I don't  think so.

Comment: No I'm not sure the problem is coming to the code, but maybe PHPMailer has more argues I dont use ?..

Comment: Does `$mail->send()` report the text of SMTP errors from the server? Does this code need to check an error code and print those?

Comment: $mail->ErrorInfo return "Échec de la connexion SMTP." (in french)

Comment: As Paul said, you need to check your return value from send - all the examples provided with PHPMailer do that, so just look at them. It's unusual to use TLS and authentication on port 25 for outbound email - I'd recommend you switch to port 587 if your server offers it. You should also [read the PHPMailer docs on this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).